# Storybook object instead of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, storybook

I have this storybook "two-row-cta.stories.js" file where i send in "rows" array but it transforms into object from some reason, anyone know why?

```js
import two_row_cta from './two-row-cta.twig';
import './two-row-cta.scss';

export default {
  title: 'Two row CTA',
};

export const two_column = () => (
  two_row_cta({
    title: 'Nunc sed',
    description: 'Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae.',
    rows: [
      [
        {
          title: 'Praesent venenatis metus',
          button: {
            title: 'Nunc interdum',
            url: '/'
          }
        },
        {
          title: 'Praesent venenatis metus',
          button: {
            title: 'Nunc interdum',
            url: '/'
          }
        },
      ],
      [
        {
          title: 'Praesent venenatis metus',
          button: {
            title: 'Nunc interdum',
            url: '/'
          }
        },
      ]
    ]
  })
);
```

[output in storybook ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkv9b.jpg)